# How to split datetime field into date and time?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have one column with datatype `datetime` and I want to take this field in twig in a split way like

```
Enter date <textbox to take date in format=YYYY:M:d>
Enter time <select box for time (format=HH:MM:SS)>
```

and I want to insert into the table in the same format which table have

eg: `2013-02-14 12:02:32`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the widget of date and time and it worked

```
 $builder->add('startDate','datetime',array(
                'date_widget'=>'single_text',
                'date_format'=>'d-M-y',
                'time_widget' => 'choice'
        ))
```

and i think this would be the way to achieve what i was expecting.